# Windows 7 black screen

Tags: windows-7, black-screen-of-death

When I startup the computer and I insert my credentials, press login, the Welcome screen appears and after that I get the black screen. I have to wait about 10 minutes and then I have to press a button and my desktop appears.

Now I have noticed, that when I unplug my network cable, I don't get the black screen. Everything is working just fine and I plug the network cable back in when my desktop is visible.

Does anyone has an idea what the cause can be?

I am running a 32 bit version on a 32 bit system and have the windows 7 ultimate edition installed.

Answer (score 1):

All I can suggest it to update the network driver and scan your system for Malware.

Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

Comment: Thnx for answering. I don't think it is Malware, because it is a fresh install of Windows 7. Directly after the first logon I got this problem.

Comment: Update the driver then.

Comment: Driver of what?

Comment: Read my answer above, I made two suggestions and identified the driver you should update.